# Why does the jtable not go transparent?

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I'm teaching myself JTable's and I'm using the example from the Oracle website.
I've tried to modify it so that I can make the JTable transparent, so I should be able to see a yellow background underneath but it just displays white. Any ideas?

Could someone point me in the right direction please, I've tried numerous solutions from google.

```
public class Test extends JPanel {

    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public Test() {

        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};

        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(322, 14));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
           table.setOpaque(false);
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class)).setOpaque(false);


        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeader(new JViewport());
        scrollPane.getColumnHeader().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);

        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        Test newContentPane = new Test();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you at least forgot to make the ScrollPane transparent... and oh, set the color on the Test panel instance, not the frame.

Comment: I've edited my code to reflect your suggestions, this doesn't fix it though

Comment: You make the ScrollPane transparent, but not its viewport. Add scrollPane.getViewPort().setOpaque(false) at the end of scrollpane initialization. There will still be some opaque parts (like the table header).

Comment: Brilliant, thats what I wanted! Is there a way to make the table header transparent as well? Thanks

Comment: There probably is (you can access the table's header through getTableHeader()), but due to its dynamic nature (it modifies whenever the column model changes) it will be difficult, probably requires subclassing JTableHeader to change at least part of its implementation. You could also simply *remove* the table header altogether (setTableHeader(null)).

Comment: @Durandal Your comments look like they should be an answer!